# How to run nvm command from bash file in GCP Cloud Shell (global install)?

Tags: bash, nvm, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-shell-editor

### What we're trying to do

We are using Cloud Shell Editor (IDE) on GCP. 
According to the [documentation for **Environment customization script**](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell#environment_customization_script):

> Cloud Shell automatically runs the script,
> `$HOME/.customize_environmen`t, when your instance boots up. Unlike
> `.profile` or `.bashrc`, this script runs once when Cloud Shell boots
> (rather than once for each shell login).
>
> This script runs as root and you can install any packages that you
> want to exist in each Cloud Shell session using Debian package
> management commands.
>
> For example, if you'd like to have erlang installed on Cloud Shell,
> your `.customize_environment` file will look like this:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> apt-get update
> apt-get -y install erlang
> ```

We are trying to pre-install node versions and automate configuration for our developers using `nvm`.

---

### Where we have issues

We've looked into several articles on making `nvm` *callable* from within a bash script file (the `.customize_environment` file):

- [nvm command not available in bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184508/nvm-command-not-available-in-bash-script)
- [Can't use nvm from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206723/cant-use-nvm-from-bash-script)
- [Node Version Manager install - nvm command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found)

None of these answers seem to resolve our issue.

#### GCP `nvm` details

Cloud Shell pre-installs `nvm` (globally); it is located at `/usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh`.
There is no `~/.nvm` folder.

I can run `nvm` without issue from Cloud Shell (command line) directly.
I cannot run `nvm` (nor using the for path) from a bash file.

#### Closest attempt

Running the following comes close, but I'm limited on privileges that you can't `sudo` around due to Cloud Shell limitations:

```
. /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 14
```

Results in:

```
Downloading and installing node v14.15.4...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.15.4-linux-x64’: Permission denied
creating directory /usr/local/nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.15.4-linux-x64/files failed
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4-linux-x64.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: /usr/local/nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.15.4-linux-x64/node-v14.15.4-linux-
Warning: x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 966)
Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /usr/local/nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.15.4-linux-x64/node-v14.15.4-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Detected that you have 4 CPU core(s)
Running with 3 threads to speed up the build
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/nvm/.cache/src’: Permission denied
creating directory /usr/local/nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.15.4/files failed
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: /usr/local/nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4.tar.xz: No such
Warning: file or directory

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 965)
Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /usr/local/nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

Important lines: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘...’: Permission denied`

I can't `sudo` around it, run `usermod` (e.g. `usermod -a -G staff $(whoami)`), even though [Google's documentation says I should be able to](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#root_user):

> When you set up a Cloud Shell session, you get a regular Unix user account with a username based on your email address. With this access, you have full root privileges on your allocated VM and can even run `sudo` commands, if you need to.

---

### Question

How can we use `nvm` within a bash script file in GCP's Cloud Shell?

Comment: I think I'm hearing that you can't sudo in your cloud shell environment?  When I try, it works.  When I run "sudo whoami" it says root.  What does yours say?  If you run the "id" command, do you see 27(sudo) in the response?

Comment: `sudo su` you can run in cloud shell and change the user to root.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210830/gcloud-components-update-permission-denied

Comment: @Kolban Thank you, this definitely helped me to find a solution! Mine was returning stuff correctly, just was thinking around the solution. You gave me a kick in the right direction.

Comment: @HarshManvar thank you, using `sudo su` actually worked, I'll post my solution and give you credit cause I use your suggestion in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this with the help of comments by [@Kolban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1738915/kolban) and [@HarshManvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5525824/harsh-manvar).

I assume this solution would also work for any other scripts that aren't working with direct calls from `.customize_environment`.

The example below is influenced by the [answer found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184512). The code installs a specific node version.

Note: `nvm` is globally installed in Cloud Shell by default.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sudo su -c '. /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install 14'
```

Comment: glad to hear that you found a solution.